# Missing values in polar plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am making a polar plot by using ggplot2.
The data near 360 are missing.
How can I show all the data?
Here are the data and the code.

```
Angle   Geno
1.252   5
329.714 5
334.74  5
348.166 5
18.29   5
3.035   5
359.855 5
358.348 5
359.855 5
9.317   5
6.195   5
355.281 5
333.29  5
349.235 5
359.855 5
1.219   5
2.058   5
342.205 5
1.764   5
345.321 5
345.234 5
337.606 5
39.661  5
328.425 5
347.59  5
348.545 5
```

And

```
i = 5
Hist_LR_Geno <- Hist_LR[Hist_LR$Geno==i,]
p5 <- ggplot(Hist_LR_Geno, aes(x=Angle))
p5 <- p5 + geom_histogram(binwidth=22.5) + 
 scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-5, 5), breaks=NULL) +
 scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,360), breaks=c(0,45,90,135,180,225,270,315)) +
 coord_polar(start=pi, direction=-1) +
 labs(x=NULL, y=NULL) +
    theme(legend.position="none",
    axis.text.x=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
    plot.margin=unit(c(-1,0,0,0), "cm"),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
    #panel.grid.major = element_line(size=0.2, color = "blue", linetype =  "solid"),
    panel.grid.minor = element_line(size=0.6, color = "blue", linetype =  "dotted"),
    axis.text=element_text(size=6))

plot(p5)
```

Here is the plot.

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: What are you trying to do? It's not clear what the expected result should be

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. The problem was about data which were not shown around marginal area, 0 degrees and 360 degrees. Parameter 'center' was necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two issues going on. First, you used `geom_histogram`, which counts the number of rows in each bin, but it looks like you might actually want the sum of `Geno` within each bin. Let's ignore that for now and go with `geom_histogram`. Please say more about what you're actually trying to do and we can come back to that issue later.

As I said, `geom_histogram` counts the number of rows in each bin. But that number of rows is greater than 5 for some of the histogram bars. However, you've set  `scale_y_continuous` with limits of `c(-5,5)`. So any bars that are taller than 5 get removed. Here's the plot with larger y limits:

```
p5 + geom_histogram(binwidth=22.5) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-5, 12), breaks=0:12) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,360), breaks=seq(0,360-45,45)) +
  coord_polar(start=pi, direction=-1)
```

[image]

**UPDATE:** Regarding your comment: Yes, I got caught by the same issue as with `scale_y_continuous`. Your `scale_x_continuous` also excludes values because the bars have width. The lowest bar extends below zero and the highest bar extends past 360, so both of those bars get excluded when the x limits are set to 0 through 360. We could expand the x limits, but then the x values would have to go from -22.5/2 to 360+22.5/2, rather than from 0 to 360.

Instead, let's change the bin locations so that the first bin fits between 0 and 22.5 (rather than between -22.5/2 and 22.5/2) and the last bin fits between 360-22.5 and 360 (rather than between 360-22.5/2 and 360+22.5/2). We can do this with the `center` parameter of `geom_histogram`. You just need to give the center of one bin and the rest will be adjusted accordingly.

```
p5 + geom_histogram(binwidth=22.5, colour="white", center=22.5/2) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-5, 14), breaks=0:15) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,360,45)) +
  coord_polar(start=pi, direction=-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, eipi10. Yes, that was a mistake. I could fix the range "limits = c(-5, 12)". However, there are still only 14 data.

Comment: Thanks again, eipi10!! "center=22.5/2" worked perfectly. Without this, the data between 0-11.25 and 348.5-360 were not shown.